# Getting "Windows Phone Emulator failed to send keyboard data.The Phone closed the connection.Some Functionality may be reduced"

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

Certain functions in WP8 emulatior isnt working like Back Button,Home Button,Accelerometer,ScreenShot function.Application is working.When clicking back button am getting error
"Windows Phone Emulator failed to send keyboard data.The Phone closed the connection.Some Functionality may be reduced"

For accelerometer am getting

Windows Phone Emulator failed to send accelerometer data.The Phone closed the connection.Some Functionality may be reduced".

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should try out the following things -

1. Restart Phone Emulator.

   otherwise,
2. Open Hyper-V Manager and delete the virtual instance of the Emulator. Also delete the snapshot and start a new instance of the emulator.

   else,
3. Open Hyper-V Manager and check the Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch from Virtual Switch Manager(Actions Pane, right side). Remove the emulator switch and start a new instance of the emulator.

Hope this helps. :)