# Wp8 Emulator not working in offline mode?

Tags: offline-mode, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm developing an application,where i update the feeds in online and during offline ,i just list out the feeds from database,it is working fine in wp7.1 emulator but not working when i disconnect the  network and tried to connect the wp8 emulator,it throws[image]
how can i test the app in Offline mode in wp8 emulator

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902405/getting-windows-phone-emulator-failed-to-send-keyboard-data-the-phone-closed-th